# Sudo works as su

Tags: linux, sudo

Ive observed kind of strange behaviour. I have openSuse and when Im in console and want to gain root access for executing one command, after typing
    sudo  
it like switches me as if Id type
    su. 
I mean -when I want to execute next commands which requires root, I just type this command without sudo.

Is this normal or is it something wrong with my system?

Comment: what you describe is the behaviour of `sudo -i` or `sudo -s`. do you perhaps have a command alias using the keyword 'sudo'? you can use 'alias' at the command line to show all your aliases.

Comment: No I do not have any aliases for sudo.... and I use sudo without any parameters;

Comment: Please specify exactly what you are running (the command) when you run `sudo`. Also, try `whoami` when it's in that "mode".

Comment: I am trying to run zypper refresh :) after sudo zypper refresh, I have to provide root pass, and after execution completes, I can run this (or any other command that requires root priviledges) just as Id do with any no-root command. 

whoami tells me that Im logged as normal user (not root).....

Comment: You shouldn't have to provide the root password. Sudo wants you to type your own password. Please paste a transcript of the session that shows everything you're doing.

Comment: I'm curious as to your output of "ls -l ` which sudo ` " to ensure you're calling what you think you're calling.